# Sequential LSTM Model - The dimensions of y_predicted is different from y_trained

Tags: python, keras, lstm, sequential

I am running an LSTM model on a simple stock market data.

When training the data, the y_train values are a simple array of floats64 of size (985,). But upon using the lstm.predict(X_test), the y_predicted values are of size array of float32 (246,2,1).

Basically, it is giving me two predictions per input X_test value. Ideally I would expect the output to be an array (246,)

Please help, here is the code:

```
def lstm_split(data,n_steps):
    X,y=[],[]
    for i in range(len(stock_data)-n_steps+1):
        X.append(data[i:i+n_steps,:-1]) 
        y.append(data[i+n_steps-1,-1]) 
        
    return np.array(X),np.array(y)



stock_data_ft = X_ft 
X1,y1 = lstm_split(stock_data_ft.values,n_steps=2)

train_split=0.8
split_idx = int(np.ceil(len(X1)*train_split))
date_index = stock_data_ft.index

X_train, X_test = X1[:split_idx] , X1[split_idx:]
y_train,y_test = y1[:split_idx] , y1[split_idx:]
X_train_date, X_test_date = date_index[:split_idx], date_index[split_idx:]

print(X1.shape , X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

print(X_train)

lstm = Sequential()
lstm.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]),activation='relu',return_sequences=True))
lstm.add(Dense(1))
lstm.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='adam')
lstm.summary()

history = lstm.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=4,verbose=2,shuffle=False)

y_pred = lstm.predict(X_test)
```

I tried to get predicted values from the model.

y_pred = lstm.predict(X_test)

Was expecting output of array (246,) but instead got an output size array of float32 (246,2,1).

Some additional clarifications:
X_train.shape[1] is 2 and X_train.shape[2] is 3. These indicate the dimensions of the input features.

Basically the X values in training data is an array of dimension (985,2,3).

Some samples below:
[[ 1.53055021, 1.52204214, 1.53825887], [ 1.5526797 , 1.56142366, 1.56073994]],

[[ 1.5526797 , 1.56142366, 1.56073994], [ 1.58880785, 1.59418392, 1.6166433 ]]]

Comment: Does the code `input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])` have something to do with the input/output shape of the LSTM?

Comment: X_train.shape[1] is 2 and X_train.shape[2] is 3. These indicate the dimensions of the input features.

Basically X values in the training data is an array of dimension (985,2,3). Some samples below:

Input sample1 : [[ 1.53055021,  1.52204214,  1.53825887],
        [ 1.5526797 ,  1.56142366,  1.56073994]],

Input sample 2:  [[ 1.5526797 ,  1.56142366,  1.56073994],
        [ 1.58880785,  1.59418392,  1.6166433 ]]]

Comment: Set `return_sequences=False` if you only want the output of the last timestep.